# NTag216 [Write] command unexpected response code

Tags: nfc, ntag21x

I'm working with NTag21x (specifically NTag216) in a C# Win-Form application

I'm having a problem with the command [Write]

Other commands are working fine, but the [Write] is returning a deferent response code (99 00);
nevertheless, the data is written anyway...
and I can [Read] them later.

Commands trace

```
pwd_auth ----------> [FF000000051BFFFFFFFF] ========> [00009000]
get_version -------> [FF0000000160] ================> [00040402010013039000]
write(4, "AAAA") --> [FF00000006A20441414141] ======> [6300]
fast_read(4, 4) ---> [FF000000033A0404] ============> [414141419000]
```

I tried the format that uses the "Data Exchange Command and InCommunicateThru" (inserting 0xD4, 0x42):

That gave me the same response (99 00) (but the data didn't get written at all).

Commands trace

```
write(4, "BBBB") --> [FF00000008D442A20442424242] ==> [6300]
fast_read(4, 4) ---> [FF000000033A0404] ============> [414141419000]
```

My reader is "ACR1281U-C1"

would you please tell me why I'm getting this response in this command?

Is this the expected response?

---